# Pygame does not update keyboard events, only mouse

Tags: python, pygame, atom-editor

I am trying to move an image and wanted to press some key on the keyboard to move dynamically through the window.

I'm doing it this way below, but notice that the image only moves when I press the keyboard key and move the mouse along:

```
import sys
import pygame

UP = False
DOWN = False
LEFT = False
RIGHT = False

pygame.init()
screen = pygame.display.set_mode((800, 600))

clock = pygame.time.Clock()    
img = pygame.image.load('tank.png')

tank = [(img), (50, 50)]

while True:
    clock.tick(60)
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            pygame.quit()

        if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
            if event.key == pygame.K_UP:
                UP = True
            elif event.key == pygame.K_DOWN:
                DOWN = True
            elif event.key == pygame.K_LEFT:
                LEFT = True
            elif event.key == pygame.K_RIGHT:
                RIGHT = True

        if event.type == pygame.KEYUP:
            if event.key == pygame.K_UP:
                UP = False
            elif event.key == pygame.K_DOWN:
                DOWN = False
            elif event.key == pygame.K_LEFT:
                LEFT = False
            elif event.key == pygame.K_RIGHT:
                RIGHT = False

        if (UP):
            tank = [tank[0], (tank[1][0], tank[1][1] - 10)]
        elif (DOWN):
            tank = [tank[0], (tank[1][0], tank[1][1] + 10)]
        elif (LEFT):
            tank = [tank[0], (tank[1][0] - 10, tank[1][1])]
        elif (RIGHT):
            tank = [tank[0], (tank[1][0] + 10, tank[1][1])]

    screen.fill((0,0,0))
    screen.blit(tank[0], tank[1])
    pygame.display.update()
```

I didn't want that to happen, I just want to press the keyboard key and move the image freely regardless of whether or not the mouse moves through the window.

How can I solve this problem?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your problem is simple - your movement code is not part of the outer while, but the inner event-loop. This results in the movement only executed in case of an event happening. Mouse or keyboard is irrelevant. See this for a somewhat improved and working version:

```
import sys
import pygame

def main():
    pressed = set()

    pygame.init()
    screen = pygame.display.set_mode((800, 600))

    clock = pygame.time.Clock()
    img = pygame.image.load('tank.jpg')

    tank = [(img), (50, 50)]

    while True:

        clock.tick(60)
        for event in pygame.event.get():
            if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
                pygame.quit()

            if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
                pressed.add(event.key)

            if event.type == pygame.KEYUP and event.key in pressed:
                pressed.remove(event.key)

        if pygame.K_UP in pressed:
            tank = [tank[0], (tank[1][0], tank[1][1] - 10)]
        if pygame.K_DOWN in pressed:
            tank = [tank[0], (tank[1][0], tank[1][1] + 10)]
        elif pygame.K_LEFT in pressed:
            tank = [tank[0], (tank[1][0] - 10, tank[1][1])]
        elif pygame.K_RIGHT in pressed:
            tank = [tank[0], (tank[1][0] + 10, tank[1][1])]

        screen.fill((0,0,0))
        screen.blit(tank[0], tank[1])
        pygame.display.update()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```